# bash: splitting stdin to multiple processes,merging outputs, ensuring known completion/output order

Tags: bash

Consider the following simplified version of a function that converts column data spat out by a terminal program into JSON...

side note: the second example might be quicker to read, to understand my underlying question.

```
function filter_proc () {

  local save=$(tempfile)
  local var1=''
  local var2=''
  local var3=''
  local var4=''


  cat > $save

  read var1 var2 var3 var4 < <(
     cat $save | grep "qualifying-line" | awk '{print $3,$4,$5,$7}'  
  );
  calculated=$((var1+var3-1))
  cat <<JSON
  {
     "header": {
       "var1": "$var2",
       "var4": "$var4"
JSON

  echo -n "   },"

  local state="column1";
  local count=0;

  for field in $(
  echo $(

      cat $save | perl -ne 'print unless 1../^MySearchTerm /'| sed -e '/^$/,$d' 
      echo -eod- 
  ) ) ; do

        case $field in 
          -eod-)
             echo -n '"count": '
             echo "$count }'


            break;
           ;;
        *)

            echo -n '"'
            echo -n "$state"
            echo -n '": "'
            echo -n "$field"
            echo -n '",'

            case $state in

               "column1") 
                state="column2"
                count=$((count+1))
                ;;
               "column2") 
                state="this_is_col3"
                ;;
               "this_is_col3") 
                state="the_fourth_column"
                ;;
               "the_fourth_column") 
                state="column1"
                ;;
            esac;

        ;;

        esac;

 done;

 rm $save
}
```

I'm trying to avoid using a temp file ($save in this example). the thing is i can't read std_in twice. i tried using tee to solve the issue, but it appears that each sub process you use with tee happens concurrently, so i can't guarantee the order of the processed output, as can be demonstrated in this asinine example:

```
time (echo hello | tee >( sleep 5 ; echo -n "first:" ; cat; ) >(sleep  3 ; echo -n "second:" ; cat;) | ( echo -n "piped:"; cat ;) ; )
```

The output of which is:
(after ~5 seconds wait - not 8 seconds as you might expect if running non currently)

> ```
> piped:hello
> second:hello
> first:hello
>
> real  0m5.030s
> user  0m0.010s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```

What's the best way of ensuring (in the second example) I get this result?

> ```
> first:hello
> second:hello
> piped:hello
>
> real  0m5.030s
> user  0m0.010s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```

bear in mind that i'd be perfectly happy for the actual time to get the answer taking 8 seconds. i just don't want to have to use temporary files, as i would prefer not to have to write to disk (sure, I could set a up a ram drive, but that's another issue entirely)

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if you had provided input and desired/actual output examples for your bash script also, but I'll have a go anyway.

In the second example, you are absolutely getting piped/second/first, and there is no way you could get anything else. The executions of second and first are concurrent, but `first` is sleeping longer than `second`, so it comes out last out of those two. `piped` is executed immediately since it is in the main pipe, and then it outputs the rest. `tee` sends a plain hello first, and then it gets the sleep 3 `second`, and then the sleep 5 `first`.

In a serious professional example, I would either:

- use python to read the columns into a data structure and spit out json directly in the desired order
- prefix everything with a number while reading it in and then pipe it through `sort -n` (sort might use a temporary file, but not unless really necessary). That would not play well with the json though.
- filter the original column input through something that prefixes it with a number (`nl`) or the timestamp, and integrate that into the json.

Comment: i find posting specific code on sites like this does not solicit serious answers. doing so normally generates "well that's not the way to do this", or "you should be using x language" sort of comments, which are not helpful. it's generally better to isolate the problem the way i would normally do myself - by factorising it down to the issue at hand. in this case, collating concurrent output streams in a cohesive manner. posting my actual code would just have confused the issue, as some would see the task at at hand as "reinventing the wheel". in my case i don't need wheels but a snow sled.

Answer (score 0):

ok, this solution is overkill for what i was originally trying to do, but
i'm posting it here in case it's useful. i ended up using named pipes and chaining them through tee. took a bit of nutting out how to lay it out presentably, but here it is. my original approached used 1 temp file, this uses 3 named pipes, so this is a little over-engineered. but it might be useful elsewhere.

EDIT: updated to let it use tempfiles.

```
#create a temp folder using whatever method we have available
function tempfolder () {
    local folder;
    which mktemp  >/dev/null && folder=$(mktemp -d) ||
       (which tempfile >/dev/null && folder=$(tempfile) &&  rm $folder && mkdir $folder) ||
          (folder="/tmp/$(basename $0)_$$" && mkdir $folder)
    echo $folder
}


function pipename() {
     echo $1/pipe${2}
  }

  function createPipes() {
      local pib=$(tempfolder);
      while [[ "$1" != "" ]] ; do
        p=$(pipename $pib $1)
        [[ ! -p $p ]] && mkfifo $p
        shift
      done;
      echo $pib;
  }

  function closePipes() {
      local pib="$1"; 
      [[ $pib = "" ]] && exit;
      rm -r $pib
  }


function tester () {





      local pb=$(createPipes 1 2 3);

       tee >(
               echo "task1:fetching" >&2
               read greeting recipient random verbage greeter; 
               echo "task1:thinking" >&2
               sleep 5;
               echo "task1:replying" >&2
               echo "task1:hello $greeter. nice to meet you. but my name is not $recipient."  > $(pipename $pb 1)             
               echo "task1:i'm done" >&2
          )  >(   
                echo "task2:fetching" >&2
                read Mr Clinton Needs A Dictionary;
                echo "task2:thinking" >&2
                sleep 3;
                echo "task2:replying" >&2
                echo "task2:It depends on what the meaning of the word $A is."> $(pipename $pb 2)
                echo "task2:i'm done" >&2

          )  >(   
                echo "task3:fetching" >&2
                read I Read random words and comment;
                echo "task3:$random is a random word"  > $(pipename $pb 3) 
                echo "task3:i'm done" >&2

          ) | (   

                cat $(pipename $pb 1) $(pipename $pb 2) $(pipename $pb 3);
                closePipes $pb 1 2 3;
          )

}

time (echo  hello world it is me - thanks | tester;)
```

Comment: I understand your problem better after seeing the solution you have found. Be careful with the [pipe size](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer).